# How can we drag and drop outlook emails into web app and how to parse .msg file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created sales-force app with drag and drop functionality. In this app we are able to drag and drop any files but i am facing problem with outlook email drag and drop. How can i drag and drop outlook emails into web app and how can i parse .msg file in JavaScript.

Comment: The .msg email files are stored in the Microsoft doc-file format. I don't think there's a good solution to handle (display, modify) them with javascript.

Comment: Then how i can achieve drag and drop outlook email and parsing?